# I want to do an insert inside an insert, error in _id? MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How to resolve "authorId: undefined"? in the author is right the _Id.
If you look at the link "Print/Image MongoDB" you will understand better

```
db.books.insert({
title:"HTML",
authorId: db.authors.insert({
    name:"Michele",
    country:"Italia",
    age:39,
    __v:0
    })._id,
publisherId: db.publishers.findOne({name:"Livraria José Olympio Editora"})._id,
price: 55,
__v:0
})
```

[Print/Image MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/it6Pc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the mongo shell the [db.collection.insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#db.collection.insert--) returns a [WriteResult](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/#writeresult--) object, not the inserted document.

**Edit**

For working in the shell, you might assign the _id to the author, then you can save both documents separately.

```
var newid = new ObjectId();
db.authors.insert({
    _id: newid,
    name:"Michele",
    country:"Italia",
    age:39,
    __v:0
    });
db.books.insert({
title:"HTML",
authorId: newid,
publisherId: db.publishers.findOne({name:"Livraria José Olympio Editora"})._id,
price: 55,
__v:0
})
```

Comment: know another way to do this?